# MySQL Update Query - Incremental Number system - Syntax Problems

Tags: php, mysql, system, points

I've got a points system in a social media script, and I'm trying to get it so that when a user makes a post, it's adds a point to their account. The points is basically a column in my "profiles" table called "totalpoints".

I've got a basic code which doesn't exactly work, but the code does call the action. So I know that my update code is not right, but I cannot work out what. So here is what it is:

```
$totalpoints = "UPDATE profiles SET totalpoints = totalpoints + 5 WHERE name = '$name'";
```

Any help from anyone would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This should work. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Did you get back any errors/warnings, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Whatever mySQL library you're using to run that query will also have a function to tell you the error info when a query doesn't work. You should use that.

Comment: Make sure that your column is `int` also. It won't work for VARCHAR if that's what you have it set to, or other type.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the type of column from VARCHAR to INT. And i did the error check, and this is what has come up: [28-Aug-2014 17:41:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 5 for Application_Model_Posts::addPost(), called in /app/core/controllers/helpers/AddPostFormLoader.php on line 111 and defined in app/core/models/Posts.php on line 337
[28-Aug-2014 17:41:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in app/core/models/Posts.php on line 353

Comment: well that's it then, in addPost function the $name variable is not defined

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with sql syntax, however it is possible that either your $name is not escaped properly and its causing query to fail, or `totalpoints` cannot be incremented because its not right datatype

Comment: How should I escape the $name properly? I can't see any problems with it :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php however if your $name is like `Mike` (does not contain ' for example) than $name should not cause query to fail. You would have to continue to debug if your column is right data type.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database, you should Make sure 'totalpoints' is stored as numeric type, like 'INT', 'BIG INT', 'DECIMAL' etc...